# Move anchor text outside of anchor tag using dom

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm using PHP's DOMDocument to parse out portions of an HTML document.

The problem:

All anchors (not links to anchors) are set up like this:

```
<a name="_Toc1234567">Overview of Data</a>
```

I want the format to be like this:

```
<a name="_Toc1234567"></a>Overview of Data
```

There are a lot of these within the document, but in all cases the anchor has a name specified --always unique.  All links do not have a name specified.

So far, I have this:

```
<?php

$d = new DOMDocument;
$d->loadHTML(file_get_contents('source.html'));

$anchors = $d->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {

      $name = $anchor->getAttribute('name'); 
      $atext = $anchor->nodeValue;

      if (isset($name)) {
        // move the anchor text outside of the anchor tag
        // like this  <a name="_Toc1234567"></a>Anchor text
      }
}

$final = $d->saveHTML();

file_put_contents("result.html", $final);
?>
```

Comment: Since no one can find a PHP DOM solution, would a PHP regular expression search and replace work?  I'm not good with regular expressions.  I did some searching and found `preg_replace()`.  Any idea how the code would look?

Comment: Out of curiosity. Why do you want to transform the result in that way?

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery is ok for you, you can do it with that code:

```
$.each($('a'), function(){
    var content = $(this).html();
    $(this).html('');
    $(this).after(content);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nikoloza/xt9ja4e0/

Comment: This will replace all links and I only want to effect the anchors (have a name specified) not the actual links to the anchors.  Also, jQuery isn't an option for me.

Comment: Then you can change `'a'` selector with that: `'a[name^="_"]'`. This demo maybe perfectly fits for you: http://jsfiddle.net/nikoloza/xt9ja4e0/2/

Comment: It's a good solution for someone.  But I can't use jQuery for this project as it has to be IE8 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new text node

```
 $textNode = $d->createTextNode ( $anchor->nodeValue );
```

and afterwards empty the nodeValue

```
 $anchor->nodeValue = '';
```

But as far as i know you need the parent and the next sibling to add the $textNode.

Read this and the comments to get an idea:
http://php.net/manual/de/domnode.insertbefore.php

Comment: thanks.  Would it help if most of the anchors were within header tags (h1,h2,h3,h4,h5) like this:  `<h3><a name="_Toc1234567">Overview of Data</a></h3>` ?